# RoR Activerecord: joining query with two associations that share a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql

I have a model called flightleg:

```
class FlightLeg < ActiveRecord::Base
      ....
      belongs_to :departure_airport, :class_name => "Airport"
      belongs_to :arrival_airport, :class_name => "Airport"
end
```

And I want to do a query on it like this:

```
Flight.joins(:airline, flight_legs: [:departure_airport, :arrival_airport]).where('departure_airport.icao_code = YBBN')
```

Of course, this doesn't work. Here is a gist of the error message:

https://gist.github.com/emilevictor/b1b7d18d5cede597c6be

I am trying to figure out how to get it all to work nicely, and be able to refer to fields of the departure and arrival airports in my query.

Comment: Please fix the syntax error in your query around `:arrival_airport)` where a closing parenthesis is encountered before the open bracket has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

There's no table 'departure_airports', but in the gist we see

```
 INNER JOIN "airports" ON "airports"."id" = "flight_legs"."departure_airport_id"
```

so can you try ('airports.icao_code = YBBN') ?

Comment: Hi DeeY!

I've tried using 'airports.icao_code' as well, but it says that there isn't a FROM clause for airports.